# Explore the series to conditional and absolute convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I check the convergence of $$\sum_{1}^{\infty}\left ( n^{n^{a}}-1 \right )$$
I have tried to do it with Cauchy.

Comment: I think Koshi is the best misspelling of Cauchy I've seen yet

Comment: I try to do it with Koshi but i havent a result

Comment: if a>1, use the ratio test and calculate $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)^a}}{n^{n^a}}=\infty$.

Comment: I dont understant you.

Comment: Ratio test: $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=L$. If $L>1$, serie does not converge.

Comment: @Admiral23 can you post your solutions? I want to see where do you make mistake using Cauchy ratio test?

Comment: I can be wrong, but anyway $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^{n^{a}}(1-\frac{1}{n^{n^{\alpha }}})}$$
As for any $$\alpha$$ we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{n^{\alpha}}}=0$$ so you have then to deal with$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^{n^{a}}}$$ and it's quite easy

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1: $a\geq 0$**

We have $a_n=n^{n^a}-1 \rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Thus, the series diverges by $n$'th term test.

**Case 2: $a<0$**

We use $n^{n^a} = \exp(n^a\log n)$. Also, we see that $n^a\log n \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Thus, 
$$
a_n = \exp(n^a\log n) -1 \rightarrow 0 \ \ \mathrm{as} \ \ n\rightarrow\infty.
$$
For this case, $n$'th term test is not applicable. Since each term is positive, the limit comparison test is applicable with $b_n = n^a\log n$. In fact, 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\exp(n^a \log n)-1}{n^a\log n}= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} \frac{e^x   -1}x=1. 
$$
Therefore, $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ both converges, or both diverges.

The sum $\sum b_n$ converges if $a<-1$, and diverges if $-1\leq a <0$. Thus, the same is true for $\sum a_n$.